# video tag not working in safari

Tags: html, safari

I am trying to play a video in safari 5 but its just showing me a blue question mark button, no video place holder no video controls (like in chrome)

```
<video poster='your_pic.jpg' controls="">
        <source width='480' height='360' src='/videos/my file to play.m4v'  />
    </video>
```

Comment: Are you using Safari on Mac or Windows?

Answer (score 1):

For safari to play videos on windows you have to install apple quick time.

http://www.agilepman.com/2010/09/how-to-make-html5-video-tag-work-in-safari-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the syntax you have used, i.e. a `source` tag within the `video` tag. I would expect a video reference to look more like this:

```
<video controls="true" poster="some-image.png" src="some-video.mp4"></video>
```

Does the video work as expected in Chrome? Looking at the controls that **do** get rendered, the difference between Chrome and Safari seems to be down to embedded Quicktime (i.e. Safari uses it if it can, Chrome does not).

One other thing: if the file just doesn't play anywhere, bear in mind that .m4v files are often MPEG4 files with Apple's Fairplay DRM applied to them (although they don't have to be).